# Real life use cases or scenarios MVI architecture in Android?

Tags: android, architecture, model-view-intent

I saw a lot of articles about MVI but everywhere these are focused on the implementation of MVI and provide some bookish or theoretical explanations. But anyone new to MVI like me is so much confusion about some questions like -

1. Why do we need MVI over MVVM as MVVM is recommended architecture by google?
2. In which real-life use cases or scenarios are MVVM handier over MVI ?

Thanks

Comment: check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59336002/4252667

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim thank you bro.. this is a really nice one. can you please add a real life demonstration/example in your answer if you have time?

Comment: here's a sample, it's a bit old but you may found the concepts declared there https://github.com/MohamedISoliman/android-MVI